# SVG: Inkscape arrowhead marker disappering after zoom

Tags: svg, zooming, inkscape

I'm drawing an SVG line with arrowhead markers, everything looks good, but in Inkscape part of the arrows disappering after zoom. Do you know if the problem is in my marker code or it's Inkscape bug? 
Addition: The lines are in group which has rotation transform.

[before zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlRev.png)

[after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg8eJ.png)

```
<marker refX="0px" 
        refY="0px" 
        orient="0" 
        overflow="visible" 
        markerWidth="7.972439" 
        markerHeight="2.65748" 
        id="arrow_right" 
        xml:space="default">
   <path d="M7.972439 0 L-3.98622 2.65748 L-3.98622 -2.65748 L7.972439 0 z"
         stroke="#FFFFFF" 
         stroke-width="0" 
         stroke-opacity="0" 
         style="fill:#000000;"
         xml:space="default" />
</marker>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Inkscape to me. File a bug with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution. It was caused by missing style in line element.
The line has to have defined "fill" to "none" together with "fill-rule" set to "evenOdd".

```
fill="none"
fill-rule="evenOdd"
```